# Is there any specific way to achieve more then 32 messages from Azure Storage Queue in one http request

Tags: azure, queue, storage

Currently I am able to get 32 messages by one request but I need more messages

Comment: do you have high throughput ? maybe azure storage queues is not the right technology for that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You can only peek or dequeue a maximum of 32 messages in a single request. This is the limitation from the REST API itself.

If you want to fetch more messages, you would need to do following things:

1. You will need to make multiple HTTP requests with each request asking for a maximum of 32 messages from the Storage Queue service.
2. You will need to [`dequeue messages`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/get-messages) instead of [`peeking messages`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/peek-messages). Peeking the messages will return you same set of messages.
3. While dequeuing the messages, you need to keep the visibility timeout duration of the messages high enough so that the same message is not returned in subsequent requests.